# Android app logout doesn't totally log out - still showing notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, android-app

I have the SE android app installed on a Nexus 4 (kitkat). I then logged out of the app on the phone. When I open the app, it (correctly) shows me the Log In options.

However, yesterday I received an inbox notification (specifically: an @ mention in a chat room). In response to this, the android app still showed the chat notification in the android notification area at the top of the screen (as well as the expanded notification area). So even though I am logged out, I am not logged out all the way.

Expected: when I am logged out of the app, I should be logged out all the way. No notifications related to the previous login credentials should be shown.

Answer (score 2):

This is a two fold problem:

1. Your device's Google Cloud Messaging token isn't being cleared on the server when you log out.
2. The app is blindly accepting accepting push notifications and showing them even if users are logged out.

<s>I went ahead and took care of #2, fixing #1 should happen soon, as of version 0.1.71 coming out later tonight this will no longer be reproducible.</s>

Aand this is now entirely fixed as of version 0.1.74 coming out later tonight.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but the regular website [shows the same problem (or at least reputation changes), using plain web sockets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203537/live-refresh-still-shows-reputation-changes-after-logging-out).