# Notifications after logging out on Android

Tags: bug, android-app

Similar to [Android app logout doesn't totally log out - still showing notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208979/android-app-logout-doesnt-totally-log-out-still-showing-notifications), but since that is a 1-year old closed bug I'm opening a new question here. 
I just installed the Android app with my user, then logout and tried to log in as another user, then logout and logged in as my normal user again. After that at some point I also restarted the phone. The problem is that I receive the notifications also for the logged-out user