# Getting push notifications for logged out account

Tags: bug, android-app, logout

I was logged in with another account A in the Android app. Then I logged out and switched to account B. The problem is I keep getting push notifications for account A, even though I logged out.

Looks like a bug to me, even a security issue.

Also does someone know a workaround? Reinstalling the app didn't help.

Comment: Are these in-app notifications or notifications to your Android device? The former would be an issue, but I can't see the latter being a problem as you've logged in with both accounts on the same device.

Comment: @ChrisF The in-app notification box is alright, I only get the push notifications to the device (if I try to open them, they don't show up in the app).

Comment: I think the resolution would be to log back in under account A and turn off push notifications, then log out and return to account B. The system has been told to send push notices for account A to a device, and whether or not you are "logged in" doesn't matter. If it did, you would have to always have the app active to get notices, and push is designed to you don't have to. How many apps would you have to keep open to get all your push notices (twitter, facebook, weather, news, &etc.)?

Comment: [Old bug that was fixed and has returned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208979/android-app-logout-doesnt-totally-log-out-still-showing-notifications/209622#209622) - not the first, and surely not the last.

Comment: I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it 2 days later, now it looks like it works properly, since I don't get any more notifications for the other account. (I guess the push tokens have been invalidated in the meantime)